# How to find non duplicate set of integer from an array that equals to the target?

Tags: algorithm

This is an interview question.

Given an array of integers and an integer target, find all
combinations which sum up to target. Don't output duplicates. e.g.,
[2,3,4], target is 5. then output should be [2,3], or [3,2], but not
both.

Comment: Is the array sorted? Do we know anything else about it (i.e. range of the numbers it holds)?

Comment: [2,3,4], target is 4, output? [2,2], [4]?

Comment: @ Zenzen, good points. However, this is the question that was asked.

Comment: @ TheHorse, [2, 3, 4] target is 4, output [4]

Comment: @q0987: well those are rather basic questions that should be answered by the interwiever :) Withouth that knowledge you can only quess what's the proper way to do it.

Comment: How a programmer deals with unknowns is an important part of the process.  If you asked questions they knew exactly how to answer, then you wouldn't learn much.

Comment: Doesn't matter - then the interviewer should say "we have no more information given"- then we can make assumptions. Saying "this is the question that was asked" isn't exactly the same. It might be only a matter of wording, but that can be very important at times!

Comment: @Zenzen: I don't think order matters, since if there's any doubt you can sort the array before you start. Skipping that sort step might theoretically be an optimization, if order can be guaranteed, but it's not worth getting into a fit about given that the main part of the problem is NP-hard (well, would be if the integers could be arbitrarily large, I expect in practice "array of integers" means "array of C `int`", so the problem is bounded). So I'd just sort 'em, and if I later discover they're pre-sorted, remove that line.

Comment: @q0987: which part are you having difficulty with? Generating unique combinations? Adding up integers to compare against the sum? Choosing a programming language for the task? SO questions aren't really supposed to be puzzles any more, you're meant to ask only about the part you can't do.

Comment: Of course you are right. Still I'll stand by my point that such questions should be answered. Obviously they don't have to give a concrete answer - something like "we don't know anything else" would suffice. Actually I don't remember meeting an interviewer who'd refuse answering them :) On the other hand in a lot of such questions the fact whether the input is sorted/we know anything more about it may simplify the whole problem a lot.

Comment: @Zenzen: I guess I'm just too used to written exams, where the rule always is that anything not stated is unknown. This despite not having sat a formal exam in over 10 years. At interview you're right, it's always worth taking a shot at getting an easier question by getting extra guarantees out of your function's caller. If nothing else, knowing the max size of the array would let us attempt to choose an algorithm that's computationally feasible in the lifetime of the universe (or of the interviewer).

Comment: Exactly. Especially when you're applying to an algorithm heavy company like Google (or MS/FB etc.) every detail counts. Here for example if the array is sorted, let's say [4,5,6] and the given number is 3 we already know that there is no such subset. This can be quite a time saver in large data sets. Same if we know the range of the numbers we can be certain that some sums are not possible to get. But as I said before, obviously there's nothing wrong with hearing from the interviewer "we have no more data on what you've asked about" then we just need to generalize.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, this is the subset sum problem.

Quoting from wikipedia's [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem):

> An equivalent problem is this: given a set of integers and an integer
>   s, does any non-empty subset sum to s?

Comment: It's actually a bit bigger than the usual subset sum problem, which is a decision problem ("does such a subset exist?") or sometimes demands an example as a proof ("if such a subset exists, exhibit one"), but doesn't normally ask for all such subsets.

Answer (score 2):

In python

```
>>> L=[2,3,4]
>>> from itertools import combinations
>>> for i in range(len(L)):
...     for j in combinations(L,i):
...         if sum(j) == 5:
...             print j
... 
(2, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is np-complete hence probably there doesn't exist an effective algorithm for solve this problem.

Comment: Nope, this isn't a knapsack problem. Even a brute force algorithm here takes at worst n^2.

Comment: well i may be off with the complexity but its definitely doable :)

Comment: @Zenzen - It is the knapsack problem? (See my answer) I think you meant 2^n.

Comment: Hm yeah the complexity seems ok, but still I'm not sure this is the knapsack problem per se. Something similar but not the same. Or am I wrong? I'm pretty sure I've read about a constant-time solution on a very similar problem somewhere. Maybe it was Concrete Mathematics?